# How to get an ui.Image from a ui.Picture in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to use [Palette Generator](https://pub.dev/packages/palette_generator) with [flutter_svg](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg).

Currently I have the following code:

```
Future<Color> colorFromSvgString(String svgAsString) async {
  final DrawableRoot svgRoot =
      await svg.fromSvgString(svgAsString, svgAsString);
  final picture = svgRoot.toPicture();
  final image = await picture.toImage(100, 100);
  final palette = await PaletteGenerator.fromImage(image);
  return palette.dominantColor.color;
}
```

This doesn't work because ´picture.toImage(100, 100)´ as per documentation does not return a rendered image. How can I obtain a rendered Image from a Picture?

Edit:

The suggested code does work, however as soon as I load the SVG from the internet it does not work anymore.

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:palette_generator/palette_generator.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

/// [color] can be null
typedef ColorWidgetBuilder = Widget Function(BuildContext context, Color color);

Future<Color> colorFromSvgString(String svgAsString) async {
  final DrawableRoot svgRoot =
      await svg.fromSvgString(svgAsString, svgAsString);
  final picture = svgRoot.toPicture();
  final image = await picture.toImage(100, 100);
  final palette = await PaletteGenerator.fromImage(image);
  return palette.dominantColor.color;
}

Future<Color> colorFromSvgAsset(String svgSourcePath) async {
  final svgAsString = await rootBundle.loadString(svgSourcePath);
  return colorFromSvgString(svgAsString);
}

Future<Color> colorFromSvgUrl(String svgUrl) async {
  try {
    final response = await http.get(svgUrl);
    return colorFromSvgString(response.body);
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}

class DominantColorFromSvgBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  const DominantColorFromSvgBuilder({
    Key key,
    @required this.svgSourcePath,
    @required this.builder,
    // ignore: prefer_asserts_with_message
  })  : assert(svgSourcePath != null),
        // ignore: prefer_asserts_with_message
        assert(builder != null),
        super(key: key);

  final String svgSourcePath;
  final ColorWidgetBuilder builder;

  @override
  _DominantColorFromSvgBuilderState createState() =>
      _DominantColorFromSvgBuilderState();
}

class _DominantColorFromSvgBuilderState
    extends State<DominantColorFromSvgBuilder> {
  Color color;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadColor();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return widget.builder(context, color);
  }

  Future<void> loadColor() async {

    // this does not work
    final c = await colorFromSvgUrl(widget.svgSourcePath);

    // this does work
    //final c = await colorFromSvgString('''<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="132.004" height="132" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><linearGradient id="b"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#3771c8"/><stop stop-color="#3771c8" offset=".128"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#60f" stop-opacity="0"/></linearGradient><linearGradient id="a"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#fd5"/><stop offset=".1" stop-color="#fd5"/><stop offset=".5" stop-color="#ff543e"/><stop offset="1" stop-color="#c837ab"/></linearGradient><radialGradient id="c" cx="158.429" cy="578.088" r="65" xlink:href="#a" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(0 -1.98198 1.8439 0 -1031.402 454.004)" fx="158.429" fy="578.088"/><radialGradient id="d" cx="147.694" cy="473.455" r="65" xlink:href="#b" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(.17394 .86872 -3.5818 .71718 1648.348 -458.493)" fx="147.694" fy="473.455"/></defs><path fill="url(#c)" d="M65.03 0C37.888 0 29.95.028 28.407.156c-5.57.463-9.036 1.34-12.812 3.22-2.91 1.445-5.205 3.12-7.47 5.468C4 13.126 1.5 18.394.595 24.656c-.44 3.04-.568 3.66-.594 19.188-.01 5.176 0 11.988 0 21.125 0 27.12.03 35.05.16 36.59.45 5.42 1.3 8.83 3.1 12.56 3.44 7.14 10.01 12.5 17.75 14.5 2.68.69 5.64 1.07 9.44 1.25 1.61.07 18.02.12 34.44.12 16.42 0 32.84-.02 34.41-.1 4.4-.207 6.955-.55 9.78-1.28 7.79-2.01 14.24-7.29 17.75-14.53 1.765-3.64 2.66-7.18 3.065-12.317.088-1.12.125-18.977.125-36.81 0-17.836-.04-35.66-.128-36.78-.41-5.22-1.305-8.73-3.127-12.44-1.495-3.037-3.155-5.305-5.565-7.624C116.9 4 111.64 1.5 105.372.596 102.335.157 101.73.027 86.19 0H65.03z" transform="translate(1.004 1)"/><path fill="url(#d)" d="M65.03 0C37.888 0 29.95.028 28.407.156c-5.57.463-9.036 1.34-12.812 3.22-2.91 1.445-5.205 3.12-7.47 5.468C4 13.126 1.5 18.394.595 24.656c-.44 3.04-.568 3.66-.594 19.188-.01 5.176 0 11.988 0 21.125 0 27.12.03 35.05.16 36.59.45 5.42 1.3 8.83 3.1 12.56 3.44 7.14 10.01 12.5 17.75 14.5 2.68.69 5.64 1.07 9.44 1.25 1.61.07 18.02.12 34.44.12 16.42 0 32.84-.02 34.41-.1 4.4-.207 6.955-.55 9.78-1.28 7.79-2.01 14.24-7.29 17.75-14.53 1.765-3.64 2.66-7.18 3.065-12.317.088-1.12.125-18.977.125-36.81 0-17.836-.04-35.66-.128-36.78-.41-5.22-1.305-8.73-3.127-12.44-1.495-3.037-3.155-5.305-5.565-7.624C116.9 4 111.64 1.5 105.372.596 102.335.157 101.73.027 86.19 0H65.03z" transform="translate(1.004 1)"/><path fill="#fff" d="M66.004 18c-13.036 0-14.672.057-19.792.29-5.11.234-8.598 1.043-11.65 2.23-3.157 1.226-5.835 2.866-8.503 5.535-2.67 2.668-4.31 5.346-5.54 8.502-1.19 3.053-2 6.542-2.23 11.65C18.06 51.327 18 52.964 18 66s.058 14.667.29 19.787c.235 5.11 1.044 8.598 2.23 11.65 1.227 3.157 2.867 5.835 5.536 8.503 2.667 2.67 5.345 4.314 8.5 5.54 3.054 1.187 6.543 1.996 11.652 2.23 5.12.233 6.755.29 19.79.29 13.037 0 14.668-.057 19.788-.29 5.11-.234 8.602-1.043 11.656-2.23 3.156-1.226 5.83-2.87 8.497-5.54 2.67-2.668 4.31-5.346 5.54-8.502 1.18-3.053 1.99-6.542 2.23-11.65.23-5.12.29-6.752.29-19.788 0-13.036-.06-14.672-.29-19.792-.24-5.11-1.05-8.598-2.23-11.65-1.23-3.157-2.87-5.835-5.54-8.503-2.67-2.67-5.34-4.31-8.5-5.535-3.06-1.187-6.55-1.996-11.66-2.23-5.12-.233-6.75-.29-19.79-.29zm-4.306 8.65c1.278-.002 2.704 0 4.306 0 12.816 0 14.335.046 19.396.276 4.68.214 7.22.996 8.912 1.653 2.24.87 3.837 1.91 5.516 3.59 1.68 1.68 2.72 3.28 3.592 5.52.657 1.69 1.44 4.23 1.653 8.91.23 5.06.28 6.58.28 19.39s-.05 14.33-.28 19.39c-.214 4.68-.996 7.22-1.653 8.91-.87 2.24-1.912 3.835-3.592 5.514-1.68 1.68-3.275 2.72-5.516 3.59-1.69.66-4.232 1.44-8.912 1.654-5.06.23-6.58.28-19.396.28-12.817 0-14.336-.05-19.396-.28-4.68-.216-7.22-.998-8.913-1.655-2.24-.87-3.84-1.91-5.52-3.59-1.68-1.68-2.72-3.276-3.592-5.517-.657-1.69-1.44-4.23-1.653-8.91-.23-5.06-.276-6.58-.276-19.398s.046-14.33.276-19.39c.214-4.68.996-7.22 1.653-8.912.87-2.24 1.912-3.84 3.592-5.52 1.68-1.68 3.28-2.72 5.52-3.592 1.692-.66 4.233-1.44 8.913-1.655 4.428-.2 6.144-.26 15.09-.27zm29.928 7.97c-3.18 0-5.76 2.577-5.76 5.758 0 3.18 2.58 5.76 5.76 5.76 3.18 0 5.76-2.58 5.76-5.76 0-3.18-2.58-5.76-5.76-5.76zm-25.622 6.73c-13.613 0-24.65 11.037-24.65 24.65 0 13.613 11.037 24.645 24.65 24.645C79.617 90.645 90.65 79.613 90.65 66S79.616 41.35 66.003 41.35zm0 8.65c8.836 0 16 7.163 16 16 0 8.836-7.164 16-16 16-8.837 0-16-7.164-16-16 0-8.837 7.163-16 16-16z"/></svg>''');
    setState(() {
      color = c;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have test with your code snippet, it works fine with demo android.svg 
you can see color 90c020 test result of this demo android.svg 
your SVG string might not correct. 
you can show it in your UI to make sure svg String is correct.

```
SvgPicture.string(rawSvg)
```

**Edit** full test code with svg from url

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/avd.dart';
import 'package:palette_generator/palette_generator.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final String rawSvg = '''<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 96 105">
  <g fill="#97C024" stroke="#97C024" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-linecap="round">
    <path d="M14,40v24M81,40v24M38,68v24M57,68v24M28,42v31h39v-31z" stroke-width="12"/>
    <path d="M32,5l5,10M64,5l-6,10 " stroke-width="2"/>
  </g>
  <path d="M22,35h51v10h-51zM22,33c0-31,51-31,51,0" fill="#97C024"/>
  <g fill="#FFF">
    <circle cx="36" cy="22" r="2"/>
    <circle cx="59" cy="22" r="2"/>
  </g>
</svg>''';

//var image;

Future<Color> colorFromSvgString(String svgAsString) async {
  final DrawableRoot svgRoot =
  await svg.fromSvgString(svgAsString, svgAsString);
  final picture = svgRoot.toPicture();
  final image = await picture.toImage(100, 100);
  final palette = await PaletteGenerator.fromImage(image);
  return palette.dominantColor.color;
}

Future<Color> colorFromSvgUrl(String svgUrl) async {
  try {
    final response = await http.get(svgUrl);
    print("${response.body}");
    return colorFromSvgString(response.body);
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
      //var color = colorFromSvgString(rawSvg);
      var color = colorFromSvgUrl("http://test.com/Android/android.svg");
      print(color.toString());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SvgPicture.string(rawSvg),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

debug image

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is pretty interesting to me that this does work. I probably should have posted a more code that I'm using. I'm loading the SVG from the internet and that does not work. See my edit. Thanks though.

Comment: also work from url. I did print response.body, Could you print response.body and see what you got?